# How to adjust historical data highs/lows for splits and dividends?

Tags: market-data

When I download historical data from yahoo finance, only the closing price is adjusted for dividends/splits.

Is there a way of figuring out the factor by which lets say the highs/lows have to be multiplied in order to adjust them for splits/dividends?

Answer (score 1):

Yahoo finance describes their method at https://help.yahoo.com/kb/finance/SLN2311.html?impressions=true  and indicate that this follows the CRSP method for adjusting prices, dividends, and volumes.  The CRSP calculations are described in detail at http://www.crsp.com/products/documentation/crsp-calculations .

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

factor = adjusted closing price / (unadjusted) closing price

Adjusted high = high * factor

Adjusted low = low * factor